# Why do polynomial equations make the shapes that they do?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I will use two examples.
$$
y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)
$$
Why does it go up then down then up again?
$$
y=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)
$$
Why does that one have two large peaks/troughs and two small ones?
Thank you for any help you are willing to give.

Comment: Hint. Figure out where it is positive and where it is negative.

Comment: title is vague.

Comment: Only two things matter when determining a polynomial's end behavior: the sign of the leading coefficient (positive or negative) and the parity of the degree (even or odd).

Comment: I hope it is obvious where the zeroes are in your examples. Since the polynomial is not zero on the entire interval, it goes up or down. But it has to get back to the x-axis to get to the next zero, so what goes up must come down and what goes down must come up.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually depends on the degree of the polynomial. So if you have $x^4$ in your equation then you would have a U shaped curve. There are many patterns you can explore by playing with coefficients and powers of $x$

Comment: Well $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ is more W-shaped than U-shaped. And it’s negative is M-shaped. Seems like you need to elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

For a polynomial of degree $n$, there will be at most $n-1$ changes in the "direction" of its graph. For example, a quadratic polynomial ($n=2$) will change direction at most once, and that's what you see in the graph: a decreasing (or increasing) part followed by a symmetric increasing (or decreasing) part.

The number of changes in "direction" (which is better known as the number of changes in concavity) has to do with the changes of sign of the second derivative of the polynomial. Every time the second derivative goes from positive to negative or from negative to positive, the polynomial changes its concavity.